# Service creation failure Microsoft Robotic Studio in "DifferentialDrive Sample"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, robotics-studio

I am So new In Microsoft  Robotic

I try to run DifferentialDrive Sample on :\Microsoft Robotics Dev Studio 4\samples\Simulation But i have Problem with Identifier ... after i running the sample it's says can not start service due to Identifier

i've checked the Code and i notice that the identifier sets to :

http://schemas.microsoft.com/robotics/simulation/services/2006/05/simulateddifferentialdrive.user.html

and it seems this is just a Unique Path

But the DSS Get the Error that says :

Service creation failure most common reasons: - Service contract identifier in manifest or Create request does not match Contract.Identifier - Service references a different version of runtime assemblies Additional information can be found in the system debugger log.

Subject Service creation failure most common reasons: - Service contract identifier in manifest or Create request does not match Contract.Identifier - Service references a different version of runtime assemblies Additional information can be found in the system debugger log.

I checked The Identifier and it's Exactly Match with my manifest file 
What should i do ??? how can i run the sample ??? or other samples

Im Running MRDS on Windows 8 64-bit ( but i compile my application on 32-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract identifier has to be in all lower case.  So, while this looks like a benign *warning*  from dssproxy.exe, it is in fact a "Failed Contract" error waiting to happen.

```
dssproxy.exe /Verbosity:d /vstarget:2010 /dll:"Blah.Y2013.M03.dll" /proxyprojectpath:"..\..\src\Blah\Proxy" /keyfile:"..\..\src\MyKey.snk" /DelaySign:false /binpath:"." /referencepath:"."

*   Processing contract class 'Blah.VersionService.Contract'
*  dssproxy: warning: The contract identifier defined by 'Blah.VersionService.Contract' has upper case characters or starts or ends with whitespace characters.
*       Identifier: http://schemas.blah.com/2014/09/Version.html
```